# How to read the formatted percentage from a cell with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, format, percentage

I am taking data from an Excel spreadsheet and inserting it into a Word document. Here is the code I am using which works as intended.

```
Private Sub insertData(wb As Excel.Workbook)
    Dim numBM As Integer
    Dim countBM As Integer
    Dim currentBM As String

    numBM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count

    For countBM = 1 To numBM
        currentBM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(countBM).Name
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(currentBM).Range.Text = wb.Names(currentBM).RefersToRange.Value2
    Next
End Sub
```

In Excel, I have some cells that are percentage type formatting. So the value of the cell is 0.857394723 but the cell displays "86%". How can I change my code so that "86%" is inserted into Word instead of "0.857394723"

Comment: Not sure why this question attracted a down vote. In it's current form it seems a valid question (not too much code, clear question, not too much context, ...). I think it is our responsibility to drop a comment when down voting (especially with new users), allowing them to learn and improve. Anyway, +1 from me puts you back at neutral score :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out the answer to this, which is extremely simple. Instead of using ...RefersToRange.Value I can use ...RefersToRange.Text so the line becomes

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(currentBM).Range.Text = wb.Names(currentBM).RefersToRange.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Format the value accordingly, using the [`Strings.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) method from the VBA standard library:

```
Dim formattedValue As String
formattedValue = Format(wb.Names(currentBM).RefersToRange.Value2,"0%")

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(currentBM).Range.Text = formattedValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out and it does work but I would have to expand my code to format some values and not others.